# My 1TB Toshiba SSD is not detected at all when I connect it to my Ubuntu 18.04 device

Tags: 18.04, ssd, toshiba

A week ago I connected the aforementioned drive and it was successfully mounted and recognised. I disconnected it without umounting or safely ejecting through the UI and since then it is not recognised by my device when I connect it. By that I mean it does not pop up in /dev, gparted does not recognise it, nor does lsusb detect anything. I have confirmed both male and female connectors are USB 3 and the device works perfectly on my ubuntu 18.04 laptop. Furthermore the same USB socket on the offending device works with USB sticks and the device is not detected by an other USB port on the desktop.

EDIT requested output of dmesg |  tail -n 40

```
[    3.435450] kvm: disabled by bios
[    3.476088] kvm: disabled by bios
[    3.484423] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.484424] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.484427] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.634965] ath9k_htc 1-6:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[    3.634966] ath9k_htc 1-6:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[    3.634967] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[    3.634967] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[    3.634968] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[    3.634968] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[    3.634969] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[    3.634969] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[    3.640300] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9271 Rev:1
[    3.641411] ath9k_htc 1-6:1.0 wlx00c0ca96c8d8: renamed from wlan0
[    4.763096] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input23
[    4.763194] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input24
[    4.763264] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input25
[    4.763330] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input26
[    4.763397] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input27
[    4.763464] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input28
[    4.763529] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input29
[    5.462733] wlx00c0ca96c8d8: authenticate with a0:04:60:04:98:36
[    5.715886] wlx00c0ca96c8d8: send auth to a0:04:60:04:98:36 (try 1/3)
[    5.739162] wlx00c0ca96c8d8: authenticated
[    5.742250] wlx00c0ca96c8d8: associate with a0:04:60:04:98:36 (try 1/3)
[    5.746132] wlx00c0ca96c8d8: RX AssocResp from a0:04:60:04:98:36 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[    5.754620] wlx00c0ca96c8d8: associated
[    5.925268] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx00c0ca96c8d8: link becomes ready
[   90.335595] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   90.335599] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   90.335601] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   90.971412] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 1408.674216] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[ 1428.917895] debugfs: File 'le_min_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!
[ 1428.917908] debugfs: File 'le_max_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!
[ 1428.917913] debugfs: File 'force_bredr_smp' in directory 'hci0' already present!
[ 1438.298262] input: 4C:87:5D:82:5E:88 as /devices/virtual/input/input30
[ 7767.043563] input: 4C:87:5D:82:5E:88 as /devices/virtual/input/input31
[ 8606.638079] perf: interrupt took too long (2501 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
```

Please help as this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Connect it and then look at the kernel messages in `dmesg | tail -n 40` to see if and how the kernel handles the drive. May be usefull to post that output here in your question. If there is no respons by the system, then perhaps it is time to make use of your warranty.

Comment: did you try rebooting your 18.04 machine? I have a 1TB WD Elements drive connected (now) to my 20.04 LTS pc and previously to an 18.04 LTS machine in an after market carrier which can be switched on and off and I experience no probems with it. Most of the time it is off but immediately recognised by the system when switched on - as was the case previously with v18.04

Comment: I posted the output of the command but am not certain if one of the lines represents the drive or not. Yes I tried rebooting the machine but with no luck.

Comment: Unplug the drive. In a terminal window, observe `sudo journalctl -f` while you plug in the drive.

Comment: I unplugged the drive executed the command and plugged it it but the output was unchanged. I cancelled the command and tried again but still no change.